# Error reading manifest file in bluemix deploy

Tags: deployment, e-commerce, ibm-cloud, devops

I'm having a hard time to deploy this standard ecommerce project on Bluemix:
https://github.com/zallaricardo/ecommerce-devops

I've chosen to do it with git repository and automatic deploy through the Bluemix pipeline service. After successfully building and fixing a lot of misconfigurations, the root challenge seems to be write a correct version of the manifest.yml file for the project.

Without the manifest.yml file, the log shows the following error:

```
Downloading artifacts...DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFUL
Target: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
Updating app loja-virtual-devops in org pfc-devops / space Dev as [email account]...
OK

Uploading loja-virtual-devops...
Uploading app files from: /home/pipeline/d38f0184-33da-44da-ba16-4671b491988a
Uploading 384.1M, 1679 files

228.5M uploaded...

Done uploading
OK

Stopping app loja-virtual-devops in org pfc-devops / space Dev as [email account]...
OK

Starting app loja-virtual-devops in org pfc-devops / space Dev as[email account]...
-----> Downloaded app package (452M)
-----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (4.0K)
Staging failed: An application could not be detected by any available buildpack

FAILED
NoAppDetectedError

TIP: Buildpacks are detected when the "cf push" is executed from within the directory that contains the app source code.

Use 'cf buildpacks' to see a list of supported buildpacks.

Use 'cf logs loja-virtual-devops --recent' for more in depth log information.
```

And with the version of manifest which I believe * - I'm new on this manifests stuff* - to be ok and sufficient, the log shows:

```
Downloading artifacts...DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFUL
Target: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
FAILED
Error reading manifest file:
yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 2: cannot unmarshal !!seq into map[interface {}]interface {}
```

The manifest.yml file is currently written as follows:

```
---
- name: loja-virtual-devops
  memory: 512M
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack
  domain: mybluemix.net
```

I'll sincerely appreciate any hint about how to fix the manifest for this application or another way to successfully deploy the project through Bluemix.

Answer (score 2):

Try including the `applications` heading in your manifest.yml file.

example:

```
applications:
- name: appname
  host: app_hostname
  buildpack: java_buildpack
  instances: 2
  memory: 512M
  disk_quota: 512M
  path: .
```

Comment: Thanks @zekone! I did it and the error progressed from applications to buildpack, which is more specific. I'll study about it but let me know if you have any insight about this:
`ERROR Compile failed with exception #<RuntimeError: No container can run this application. Please ensure that you’ve pushed a valid JVM artifact or artifacts using the -p command line argument or path manifest entry. Information about valid JVM artifacts can be found at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#additional-documentation. >
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed`